# How voltage drop is determined for a circuit with open ends in between

Tags: dc

I am trying to solve a circuit for initial conditions and transient response.

the circuit is like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQqMLj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At `t = 0-`, equivalent circuit will be like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiYyL4.png)</sup>

In the textbook I am currently reading, It says `Vc(0-)` is 10V but `Va(0-)` is 0.

How can that be? Can somebody explain this to me?

Book that i am referencing: https://ibb.co/f8TQ5Wg

Question: https://ibb.co/XYJRZN5

Comment: Which textbook is this from? Seems to me that the voltage at node Va is not 0V, but 10V.

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Comment: I'm preparing for my exams :)

Comment: Sounds like a typo.

Comment: I've updated the question with book cover image and question image from the book

Comment: @Andyaka, so u mean voltage at `a` and the capacitor `C`, both should be `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent circuit at `t=0-`:

[image]

For convenience, I have removed `C1`, since at `t=0-`, it acts like an open circuit.

Note the red currents first - they're all `0A`, since no current flows through an open circuit. Since those currents are `0A`, we can deduce from KCL that the green current is also equal to `0A`.

From here, it should be trivial to deduce the voltages at nodes `Va` and `Vc` for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I kind of understand the current flow. Now I'm again confused how to determine the Voltages at the node `a` and the voltage at the capacitor. Do you think both values should be zero?

Comment: I want to guide you in the right direction, not just give you the answer. Consider this: If **the only voltage source** in this circuit supplies no current to the resistors, how much current will flow through them? And how much is the voltage **drop** going to be on them based on that?

Comment: Since `V=IR`, and if Current is zero over any unit, I assume the voltage should be zero. Is this the same with the capacitor? Because V has different expression for capacitor.

Comment: Almost there! `V=IR` tells you the voltage *drop* across the resistors - you're interested in finding the voltage on specific nodes. Hint: start with node `Va`.

Comment: Or if there is no drop at R2, does that mean Va would be 10V?

Comment: Bingo. Now you can easily find out `Vc`!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146612/discussion-between-kiran-parajuli-and-uriyabsc).

Comment: @KiranParajuli, if my answer was helpful to you, please mark it as accepted, since it is common practice here.

Comment: Please let me confirm the answer is actually correct and the textbook was wrong. Some other opinions are also here in the answers. I will find out the actual explanation and give it the reaction. Btw, a big thank you for your helpful answer & comments for the question. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Fair enough - You could also very easily simulate this circuit and confirm the results for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With both SW1 and C1 assumed to be open, no current flows.
When no current flows, the voltage drop over any resistor is zero.

Therefore, everything at the top of the circuit is at 10 V, and everything at the bottom of the circuit is at 0 V.

Comment: I think there would not be any current flow in the circuit. So how the top part is at `10V`. Also, may i ask what is the top part exactly :) ?

Comment: The top part is anything connected to the 10 V pin of the voltage source.

Comment: Okay. So u mean both `Vc` and `Va` at `t=0-` will be `10V` as both are connected to the `+ve` end of the voltage source.